Both shift keys and down arrow are no longer working
Context: I have a Dell XPS 13 (2022) 9315 running Void Linux with kernel 6.6.57_1. I can't use both Shift and dot keys (it's the problem), so sorry in advance for the way I wrote this question.
The problem:

This morning everything was still fine. I performed a
sudo zzz

before going to my office
When I reopened my laptop, it woke up as usual, but both Shift keys and the Down arrow keys are suddenly no longer working.
I tried to reboot, do some updates (there is no update at the moment), update the BIOS (already up-to-date) but nothing changed.
I tested all the keys with xev, so I'm sure that only both Shift keys and the Down arrow key are not working, but I don't understand why.

I tried some old solutions found on the site, like

blacklist Intel vbtn in modprobe and reboot (doesn't work)
reinstall the X-server and reboot (doesn't work)

I have no external keyboard available. Does anyone have an idea ?
Update: for no reason, the Down arrow key now works again.

since a reboot doesn't change things, my best guess would be a hardware defect

i just added an update : for no reason at all, the down arrow key work again, i don't understand
